# resolve java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet in Vaadin maven project

Tags: java, maven, vaadin, classnotfoundexception, m2e

currently we are working on an vaadin application using maven3 and git. We set up the project using the m2e Eclipse plugin and the arche-type "vaadin-archetype-clean". We have some dependencies to other maven projects. The problem is that the project is only working on my maschin (osx). After we pull it from git and added the projects via m2e addon to Eclipse, we get after publish it to tomcat v7 Servercode: 500

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:133)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1136)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:857)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

We tried multiple mvn:clean, install, dependencys resetting, reimport, using the files from my maschine. The web.xml and pom.xml should be auto generated. We set all versions to SNAPSHOT. All machines have Eclipse Juno Java EE, jdk 1.6 and the newest m2e addon. Gitignore is

```
Kino/build
Kino/WebContent/VAADIN/widgetsets/*
*.class
ExcelImporter/.classpath
ExcelImporter/.project
ExcelImporter/.settings/
.metadata/
target/
```

Where Kino is the vaadin application and ExcelImporter one of the dependence projects. We also tried to you my data (folder) on the other machines. Did not worked :(.

Comment: What does your pom.xml look like?

Answer (score 0):

How did you package the app?

You should write:

mvn compile
mvn war

And then make sure it runs under Jetty:

mvn jetty:run

Or simply deploy to Tomcat.